# why my geometry node is not working?

Tags: rendering

[image]I am trying to use geometry node to create a cyber punk city but I can not see my buildings distributed on my plain. I do not understand what am I doing wrong? Kindly help . I am adding a picture too.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only „see“ something in geometry nodes if you choose an object for your point instance node.

Comment: oh, ok now i get it thank you @chris

Comment: i am trying to use collection in instance node to add building but it is not working

Comment: tap on "collection" in the point instance node and then choose your collection. Of course in the collection there should be objects.

Comment: Chris is the man for Geometry Nodes

Comment: @moonboots: thank you 

Comment: yes i have but it is still not showing . For your reference i have added an image kindly check

Comment: Ok, please provide blend file